# Developing a custom partitioner in Cassandra

Tags: cassandra

I would like to develop a custom partitioning strategy in Cassandra for research purposes. I couldn't find a decent tutorial in that regard. As far as I am concerned, I am supposed to provide an implementation for the [IPartitioner](https://github.com/apache/cassandra/blob/trunk/src/java/org/apache/cassandra/dht/IPartitioner.java) interface. I am not quite sure whether I know the expected semantics of all methods or perhaps I need to implement other classes too.

Is this process documented somewhere? Is there any forum or existing discussion that I can read through? Or an informative blog post?

Comment: That's kind of a cool idea.  Probably the best place to ask about that would be the Apache Cassandra Developer mailing list.  You can subscribe here: dev-subscribe@cassandra.apache.org

Comment: ask in the cassandra devel list... And look into the existing implementations